# Searching for acronym keywords in Google brings up full domain as first result

Tags: seo, google, keywords, meta-description, meta-keywords

For years, I've had two domains (this is a ficticious example):
`allbenchescatchdirt.com` and `abcd.com`

They both do okay in terms of ranking for their keywords. However, I noticed something weird:

If I search for "**abcd**", the domain, `allbenchescatchdirt.com`, shows up as the first result and `abcd.com` shows up as second.

I have a 301 redirect on `allbenchescatchdirt.com` and the *title* tag of `abcd.com` is "**abcd**" and I've made sure that the keywords are placed accordingly in the content.

I know it's difficult to provide information without knowing what the real domain is, but from a first glance, any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Sounds like Google is caching your results from the way you have clicked previously. If using Chrome do a CTRL+SHIFT+N to open incognito and once in that window navigate to Google and do the same search this time with no Google Cookies or Tracking enabled. Let us know.

Comment: @bybe: That isn't the case here. If I go incognito, it's the still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake! It looks like there was a 302 redirect on the full domain. I've now changed it to a 301, so I believe this should take care of the issue.